# How to save selected check boxed options to database and generate unique order number that will be searched on separate page?

Tags: php, html

I have created a database to store information like the users and certain information like salary, job categories, etc. I have 2 pages set up using html and php mainly. I have it set so that the New Requests page you can search for potential employees based on cert info (job cat, salary, etc). What I'm trying to do now is be able to select 3 potential employees and save it as an order (like if you were shopping online or something and you bought multiple items in one order) and have it display the order number, possibly with the alert that I created. Then I want to be able to search that order number on my 2nd page, called My Staffing Requests, and it display the order that was saved on the previous page. How would I go about doing that? I've looked a little into using a $session, but I'm not sure how to start that process or if thats what I need. Any directions as to where to start would be fantastic.

Here is the New Staffing Requests page

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php'; 
    protect_page();
    include 'includes/overall/overallheader.php'; 
?>

<h1>New Staff Request</h1>

<p>Search for potential staff by job categories using the form below</p>


<form method="POST">
    <input type="TEXT" name="search" />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="searchquery" value="Search" />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="save" Value="Add Request">
</form>
<br/>

<p><b> Select only up to 3 results</b></p>
<form method="post" action="StaffingRequest.php">
    <?php


        if(isset($_POST['searchquery'])){

            $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','lr');
            $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
            $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE jobcat LIKE '%$search%'");
            if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
                    $education = $rows['education'];
                    $salary = $rows['salary'];
                    $jobcat = $rows['jobcat'];
                    echo '<br /><input id="query" type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="'.$first_name.'  '.$last_name.' </br>'.$jobcat.' </br>'. $education .' </br>' .$salary .'</br></br>"> First Name: ' .$first_name. '<br />Last Name: ' .$last_name. '<br />Job Category: ' . $jobcat. '<br /><br />';
                }
            } else {
                echo "No Results";
            }
        }


    $message = "Contact manager will valiate your staffing request within 24 hours.";
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }


    ?>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  var = lastSelection;

  $('#query').change(function(event){

    if ($(this).val().length > 3) {

      $(this).val(lastSelection);
      alert("You may only select three options.");

    } else {
      lastSelection = $(this).val();
      }
  });
});

</script>
<?php include 'includes/overall/overallfooter.php'; ?>
```

Here is the My Staffing Requests page:

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php'; 
    protect_page();

    include 'includes/overall/overallheader.php';
?>
      <h1>My Staff Requests:</h1>
      <p>Search by request ID number.</p>

    <form method="POST">
    <input type="TEXT" name="search" />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="ordernumsearch" value="Search By Request ID" />
    </form>
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $chkbox = $_POST['query'];
 $i = 0;
 While($i < sizeof($chkbox))
 {

 echo "" . $chkbox[$i] . '</br>';

 $i++;
 }

 }

        if(isset($_POST['ordernumsearch'])){

            $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','lr');
            $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
            $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id LIKE '%$search%'");
            if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
                $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
                    $education = $rows['education'];
                    $salary = $rows['salary'];
                    $jobcat = $rows['jobcat'];
                    $canrelocate = $rows['canrelocate'];
                    echo '<br />Request ID: '.$user_id.'<br/>First Name: ' .$first_name. '<br />Last Name: ' .$last_name. '<br />Job Category: ' . $jobcat. '<br/>Education: ' .$education. '<br/>Salary: ' .$salary. '<br/>Can Relocate: ' .$canrelocate. '<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">Valid</br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2">Invalid</br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3">Unable to Fill</br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio4">Fill</br>

                    <br />';
                }
            } else {
                echo "No Results";
            }
        }



    ?>

    <input type="SUBMIT" name="save" Value="Save">
</form>

<?php include 'includes/overall/overallfooter.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think session is a good solution but if you are a difficulty you can use global variable(or cookie).

a link where you can read how to use global variable:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

$GLOBALS is a PHP super global variable which is used to access global variables from anywhere in the PHP script.

when you have more time read SESSION
link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

**What is a PHP Session?**

When you work with an application, you open it, do some changes, and then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who you are or what you do, because the HTTP address doesn't maintain state.

Session variables solve this problem by storing user information to be used across multiple pages (e.g. username, favorite color, etc). By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

Start a PHP Session
A session is started with the session_start() function.

Session variables are set with the PHP global variable: $_SESSION.

an example: file1.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>
......
</body>
</html>
```

**Get PHP Session Variable Values** file2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The Session finish when the user does log out...

I hope this is helpful you.